# Is there an Api for my android app sync chrome pc bookmarks?

Tags: android, google-chrome, synchronization

I want to sync chrome pc bookmarks to my Android application. how  could I find a google official chrome api(java) to sync my chrome bookmarks in pc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer but... there isn't one.  We don't expose that feature to third integrations.

Comment: So why can "CocCoc" do it? coccoc.com